# a specific integral to compute

Tags: real-analysis

What is

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\int_1^4\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}dx$ ?

It may happen that $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}$ does not have a primitive function (so the Newton-Leibniz formula is excluded) but this I cannot prove. Can you come up with a successfull computation?

Comment: An antiderivative exists for any interval $[a,b]$ where $b>a>0$ since the integrand is continuous on that interval. The discontinuity at $x=0$ is not an issue here since your interval of integration excludes this point. Anyway, the antiderivative is not an elementary function. Do you want a closed-form computation or something else?

Comment: @bjorn93 Closed-form would be the best but I am stuck at the very beginning so any kind of hint is welcomed. By the way, how can you see that the anti-derivative is not an elementary function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing an elliptic integral.

What you can do is a series expansion.
Start using $x=\frac 1 y$
$$\int\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}\,dx=-\int\frac{\sqrt{1+y^4}}{y^2}\,dy$$

Using  a binomial theorem, we have
$$-\frac{\sqrt{1+y^4}}{y^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2 n)!  }{4^n(2 n-1) (n!)^2}\,y^{4 n-2}$$
Integrating termwise
$$\int -\frac{\sqrt{1+y^4}}{y^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2 n)!  }{4^n(2 n-1)(4n-1) (n!)^2}\,y^{4 n-1}$$
and use as bounds $1$ and $\frac 14$.

Computing the partial sums (from $n=0$ to $n=p$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 1 & 3.16406 \\
 2 & 3.14621 \\
 3 & 3.15189 \\
 4 & 3.14928 \\
 5 & 3.15072 \\
 6 & 3.14983 \\
 7 & 3.15043 \\
 8 & 3.15001 \\
 9 & 3.15032 \\
 10 & 3.15008 \\
 11 & 3.15027 \\
 12 & 3.15012
\end{array}
\right)$$

the exact value being $3.15018$.